# Windows service timer issue

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have developed windows application which will watch source folder if it finds any folders under source it will move that folder to process folder after performing some operation in process folder it will move those folders  destnation folder or Error folder.
This Windows application i converted to windows service and i make this service will call every 30 seconds but now i am not getting how to check before calling service next time previous process completed or not if it not complete  how to avoid calling service again.

I added timer interval for 30 sec but process may take more than 30 sec(unpredictable).

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
   timer.Interval = 30000; //5000number in milisecinds  
   timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

```
private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{           
   foldermovinglogic();
}
```

Comment: 1. disable timer before and enable after ... 2. add some bool var and check and set before and set after ... Did you tried those obvious solutions?

Comment: i have tried 2nd  option added booll var to check but can you please explain timer set before and after

Comment: `time.Enabled = false` before `foldermovinglogic()` and back to true after?

Comment: Thank you it resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating things, .Net has a built in [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8) which will drop a event when something in the directory was changed, from there on you can filter by created folders, and compare the subfolders now against the subfolders on the last change and do what you intend to do with the newly created folders.

An example for you:

```
using System.IO;
```

1. Declare the FileSystemWatcher

```
private static FileWatcher yourFileWatcher;
```

2. Initialize the FileSystemWatcher

```
yourFileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(directory);
yourFileWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
```

3. OnCreated is where you compare the now structure to the past structure it hasto have the following Format:

```
private void FSW_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
```

See this [tutorial](https://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/verzeichnis-ueberwachen-mit-dem-filesystemwatcher/146)